# Cannot install rmagick gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rmagick

When i run the bundle install command I get the following error:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Users/delisdeli/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/build_tarball.rake
An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I then ran "sudo gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'" and get the following:

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

```
Successfully installed rmagick-2.13.2
Parsing documentation for rmagick-2.13.2
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/RMagick2.bundle, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmagick.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmdraw.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmenum.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmfill.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmilist.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmimage.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rminfo.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmmain.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmmontage.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmpixel.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmstruct.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ext/RMagick/rmutil.o, skipping
unable to convert "\xCF" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/RMagick2.bundle, skipping
1 gem installed
```

However when I run bundle install again, I get the same output as the first try, any advice? :(

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need update your rdoc:

```
gem update rdoc
```

Then try install rmagick again.

Or if you prefer not to reinstall.

```
gem rdoc --all --overwrite
```